# Const variable in a global struct in C

Tags: c, struct, header, constants

I'm trying to define a set of constant variables inside a global struct in C. So far, I have a header file "params.h":

```
#ifndef PARAMS_H_INCLUDED
#define PARAMS_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Params_s {

    const int nSamples;
    //Some other constants here...

} Params;

extern const Params params;

#endif
```

I also have a file "params.c" to define my constants:

```
#include "params.h"

Params params = {

    8*1024, // nSamples
    //Some other constants here...

}
```

My problem occurs when I try to use these constants to define things like array sizes. If, in a third .c file, I write:

```
#include "params.h"

//...Code here...

double p[params.nSamples];
```

Then I end up with the following error appearing on the array size:

```
IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value
```

Have I incorrectly declared my constants?

Comment: Just use a preprocessor definition (macro) instead: #define N_SAMPLES (8*1024)

Comment: Do you initialize the Params structure in the third .c file again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That means it should use values like `2, 3, 10` and not like variable `n`

As I can see your value is constant so you could use

```
#define NSAMPLES 8192
```

and use like

```
double p[NSAMPLES];
```

Even better way is , go for dynamic allocation

```
double* p = malloc(sizeof(double)*params.nSamples);
```

Comment: So you're telling me that _every time_ I want to use the value of nSamples, I need to explicitly write 8*1024? What do I do if I've added a couple of hundred references to the value of 8*1024 samples, and in a few weeks time I need to change the design to deal with 10*1024 samples? How does anyone ever manage a large code base?

EDIT - ah, you've edited your post. I guess the closest to my current code would be to use #define. Is there any way of doing #define with a struct like params? I'm translating some MATLAB code, and it'd be nice to keep the structure as close as possible...

Comment: @user2823789 Err.. I am not saying anything. I gave you few options to work with. You chose yours.

Comment: @user2823789 _extern const Params params;_ Also by seeing this.. I don't think you are going to change nSamples run time. Its constant!

Comment: Sorry, when I saw your post it only read "Yes. That means it should be like 2, 3, 10 and not like variable n"

Comment: :). Its okay. Good you got your answer!

Comment: One should perhaps add, that `const` qualified variables are just that, variables, and not "constants" in the sense of the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

In C89, you cannot declare array with a variable length. If you want to do that, you will have to allocate it yourself via `malloc` or similar functions and then free up your memory.

If you still want to do that, you can use C99, by compiling with flag `--std=c99` on gcc for example. It will allow you to declare such arrays.

As other said, if you just want to allocate it without using your structure, you're still able to make a `#define`.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here

double p[params.nSamples];

try to give a value there in spite of variable at the place of size